How to use the function in vis-network.js to convert color names to hex values?
https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js,  How can I use the existing functions or dictionaries in vis-network (dict which named cv in vis-network.min.js) to convert a color name (such as "red") to a hexadecimal value (#FF0000)?
